# TSan in GCC reports errors that Clang does not

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, clang++, thread-sanitizer

I've implemented a locked hash table and I've created a unit test of the same to test concurrent read/writing to the table. After thread sanitisation with clang (AppleClang), it reports no errors but GCC (g++8) on the other hand spills lines of what I think are false positives. Or could they be genuine? I've tested the code a large number of times with clang for the same and couldn't find a logical error.

Locked Lookup Table code:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value, typename Hash = std::hash<Key>>
class LockedLookupTable
{
    class bucket_type;
public:
    typedef Key key_type;
    typedef Value mapped_type;
    typedef Hash hash_type;

    LockedLookupTable(unsigned num_buckets = 19, const Hash &hasher_ = Hash())
    : _buckets(num_buckets), hasher(hasher_)
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_buckets; ++i)
            _buckets[i].reset(new bucket_type);
    }

    LockedLookupTable(const LockedLookupTable &other) = delete;
    LockedLookupTable &operator=(const LockedLookupTable &other) = delete;

    Value at(Key const &key, Value const &default_value = Value()) const
    {
        return get_bucket(key).at(key, default_value);
    }

    void insert(const Key &key, const Value &value)
    {
        get_bucket(key).insert(key, value);
    }

    void erase(const Key &key)
    {
        get_bucket(key).erase(key);
    }

    std::map<Key, Value> get_map() const
    {
        std::map<Key, Value> res;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < _buckets.size(); ++i) {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_buckets[i]->_mutex);
            for (typename bucket_type::bucket_iterator it = _buckets[i]->data.begin();
                 it != _buckets[i]->data.end();
                 ++it) {
                res.insert(*it);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    int max_collisions() { return _buckets[0]->data.size() ? _buckets[0]->data.size() - 1 : 0; }

    std::size_t size()
    {
        std::size_t count = 0;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < _buckets.size(); ++i) {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_buckets[i]->_mutex);
            for (typename bucket_type::bucket_iterator it = _buckets[i]->data.begin();
                 it != _buckets[i]->data.end();
                 ++it) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<bucket_type>> _buckets;
    Hash hasher;

    bucket_type &get_bucket(Key const &key) const
    {
        const std::size_t bucket_index = hasher(key) % _buckets.size();
        return *_buckets[bucket_index];
    }

    class bucket_type
    {
        typedef std::pair<Key, Value> bucket_value;
        typedef std::vector<bucket_value> bucket_data;

    public:
        typedef typename bucket_data::iterator bucket_iterator;

        Value at(Key const &key, Value const &default_value)
        {
            boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_mutex);
            bucket_iterator const found_entry = find_entry_for(key);
            return (found_entry == data.end()) ? default_value : found_entry->second;
        }

        void insert(Key const &key, Value const &value)
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_mutex);
            bucket_iterator found_entry = find_entry_for(key);

            if (found_entry != data.end())
                data.erase(found_entry);

            data.push_back(bucket_value(key, value));
        }

        void erase(Key const &key)
        {
            boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(_mutex);
            bucket_iterator const found_entry = find_entry_for(key);
            if (found_entry != data.end())
                data.erase(found_entry);
        }

        bucket_data data;
        mutable boost::shared_mutex _mutex;

    private:
        bucket_iterator find_entry_for(Key const &key)
        {
            return std::find_if(data.begin(), data.end(),
                [&](bucket_value const &item)
                {
                    return item.first == key;
                });
        }
    };
};
```

Test Code:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(LockedLookupTableTest)
{
    clock_t int_begin = clock();
    LockedLookupTable<int, int> table(MAX_BUCKETS);
    std::atomic<bool> go{false}, done_read{false}, done_write{false}, fail{false};
    std::thread *r[MAX_THREADS], *w[MAX_THREADS];

#if SPLIT_THREADS
    printf("Dividing work between %d reader + %d writer threads: %d per thread.\n", MAX_THREADS, MAX_THREADS, (MAX_TABLE_SIZE/MAX_THREADS));
#endif

    // Populate for reading
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_TABLE_SIZE; j++)
        table.insert(j, j);

    // Readers
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        r[i] = new std::thread([&go, &table, &done_read, &fail, i] () {
#if SPLIT_THREADS
            int start = MAX_TABLE_SIZE / MAX_THREADS * i;
            int end = start + MAX_TABLE_SIZE / MAX_THREADS;
#else
            int start = 0;
            int end = MAX_TABLE_SIZE;
#endif
            while (!go);

            clock_t t_begin = clock();

            for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
                int val = table.at(j);
                if (j != val) {
                    char output[256];
                    sprintf(output, "INT/INT not equal: %d != %d\n", j, val);
                    done_read = true;
                    fail = true;
                    return;
                }
            }

            done_read = true;
            printf("INT/INT Thread #%d - Read Time %.5fs\n", i, double(clock() - t_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        });
    }

    // Writers
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        w[i] = new std::thread([&go, &table, &done_write, i] () {
#if SPLIT_THREADS
            int start = MAX_TABLE_SIZE / MAX_THREADS * i;
            int end = start + MAX_TABLE_SIZE / MAX_THREADS;
#else
            int start = 0;
            int end = MAX_TABLE_SIZE;
#endif
            while (!go);

            clock_t t_begin = clock();

            for (int j = start; j < end; j++)
                table.insert(j, j);

            done_write = true;
            printf("INT/INT Thread #%d - Write Time %.5fs\n", i, double(clock() - t_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        });
    }

    go.exchange(true);

    while (table.size() < MAX_TABLE_SIZE && !done_read && !done_write);

    if (fail)
        BOOST_FAIL("Failed read.");

    printf("INT/INT Read/Write Test Finished in %0.5fs\n", double(clock() - int_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    int_begin = clock();

    // Map Iteration
    std::map<int, int> map = table.get_map();
    int i = 0;
    for (auto c : map) {
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(i, c.second);
        i++;
    }

    printf("INT/INT Map Iteration Test Finished in %0.5fs\n", double(clock() - int_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // Final Integrity Check
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_TABLE_SIZE; j++)
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(j, table.at(j));

    printf("INT/INT Finished in %0.5fs\n", double(clock() - int_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        if (r[i]->joinable()) r[i]->join();
        if (w[i]->joinable()) w[i]->join();
        delete r[i];
        delete w[i];
    }

    done_read.exchange(false);
    done_write.exchange(false);
    go.exchange(false);

    // Erase table contents.
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        w[i] = new std::thread([&go, &table, i] () {
#if SPLIT_THREADS
            int start = MAX_TABLE_SIZE / MAX_THREADS * i;
            int end = start + MAX_TABLE_SIZE / MAX_THREADS;
#else
            int start = 0;
            int end = MAX_TABLE_SIZE;
#endif
            while (!go);

            clock_t t_begin = clock();

            for (int j = start; j < end; j++)
                table.erase(j);

            printf("INT/INT Thread #%d - Erase Time %.5fs\n", i, double(clock() - t_begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        });
    }

    go.exchange(true);

    while (table.size() > 0);

    printf("INT/INT Collisions: %d\n", table.max_collisions());

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        if (w[i]->joinable()) w[i]->join();
        delete w[i];
    }
}
```

GCC-8 TSan errors: https://travis-ci.org/horizonxyz/horizon/jobs/507336127#L1424

AppleClang errors: https://travis-ci.org/horizonxyz/horizon/jobs/507336131#L2950

Comment: This code is huge. Please minimize it to the point it is easy to reason about. Start by removing functions that are not needed for reproduction, and do not participate in the compilation of the example

Comment: @MichaelVeksler ok, I've removed the part of the test which tests a table of string keys, since the code is basically the same.

Comment: Can you also post the error? The link is useless: *This log is too long to be displayed. Please reduce the verbosity of your build or download the raw log.*

Comment: Also, the code is still big

Comment: @MichaelVeksler There are a large number of errors from GCC, I'm not sure which to post here so I've posted the link and the responsible code here.